# What is the real importance of RAM Timing?

Tags: memory

When we choose memory for our stuff or servers we always are careful about Memory Size , Bus Speed, but most people never care about RAM timing; what is the meaning of this feature, and what is its real importance?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_timings) seems to answer all your questions.

Comment: -1: Your question does not show research effort. Please edit your question to add more specific information so that we can answer it more effectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://www.masterslair.com/memory-ram-timings-latency-cas-ras-tcl-trcd-trp-tras) is a good explanation of RAM timings, which would be the four numbers after the bus speed of the RAM.  These values control various timings related to how the memory controller talks to the RAM.

> 1. CAS Latency (tCL) - This is the most important memory timing. CAS
>    stands for Column Address Strobe. If a row has already been selected,
>    it tells us how many clock cycles we'll have to wait for a result
>    (after sending a column address to the RAM controller).
> 2. Row Address (RAS) to Column Address (CAS) Delay (tRCD) - Once we send the memory controller a row address, we'll have to wait this many
>    cycles before accessing one of the row's columns. So, if a row hasn't
>    been selected, this means we'll have to wait tRCD + tCL cycles to get
>    our result from the RAM.
> 3. Row Precharge Time (tRP) - If we already have a row selected, we'll have to wait this number of cycles before selecting a different row.
>    This means it will take tRP + tRCD + tCL cycles to access the data in
>    a different row.
> 4. Row Active Time (tRAS) - This is the minimum number of cycles that a row has to be active for to ensure we'll have enough time to access
>    the information that's in it. This usually needs to be greater than or
>    equal to the sum of the previous three latencies (tRAS = tCL + tRCD +
>    tRP).

Lower is better for these values.

You can't damage the RAM by changing any of these values (unlike modifying bus speed or voltage), if the RAM can't handle it, it just won't interact with the CPU properly and your system will lock up or crash.

The sticker values are stored on the RAM's serial presence detect (SPD) EEPROM, but some motherboards can override them.  The manufacturer has tested the RAM at the provided values, so if you deviate from the manufacturer's specifications the RAM may not work reliably (long Memtest86 test sessions are recommended if you do play with these values.)

Comment: big ty, is a very full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

RAM timing is basically a measure of latency. It is the number of cycles it takes between when the RAM receives a command from the processor to when the processor can expect a stable response.

Depending on the use of the servers the impact of ram timings on performance may vary. RAM timings do not impact the total bandwidth of the ram, which is determined by the bus speed and they do not impact capacity. The latency of ram is already so low compared to SSD or HDD drives and other methods of storing data, that when used as storage for hot data it is much more beneficial to have large capacity and bandwidth than to worry about timings. Servers also often use Registered/Buffered DRAM that helps to allow larger capacities at the cost of more latency/worse timings.

Ram Timings can indicate overclock potential or small performance increases, but this is primarily of interest to enthusiast overclockers, not people who are designing reliable, high capacity servers.